# Unaligned memory reference when reading and storing multiple strings

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

I'm trying to read multiple strings from a file and store them all together. The way the input is designed, the following preconditions are guaranteed:

1. The number of string I have to read in is pre-determined
2. The length of all strings (including a newline and a NUL-byte) is the same

I have the following code, however I've been running into an unaligned memory word reference error the second time the loop is entered.

```
    .data
    .align 4
aLine:
    .space 128
arr:
    .space 1024

    .text
//...
//...
build:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-24
    sw  $ra, 20($sp)
    sw  $s4, 16($sp)
    sw  $s3, 12($sp)
    sw  $s2, 8($sp)
    sw  $s1, 4($sp)
    sw  $s0, 0($sp)

    li  $t0,0    #incrementing value for index
    move    $s0,$a0   #$a0 is the number of strings
    addi    $s1,$a1,2   #$a1 is the length of each string, $s1 makes room for the newline character and the null
    la  $a2,arr

build_loop:
    beq $t0,$s0,build_done
    li  $v0, READ_STRING   #READ_STRING is set to 8 earlier in the program
    la  $a0,aLine
    move  $a1,$s1
    syscall
    mul $t1,$t0,$s1
    add $t2,$t1,$a2
    sw  $v0,($t2)
    addi    $t0,$t0,1
    jal build_loop

build_done:

    lw  $ra, 20($sp)
    lw  $s4, 16($sp)
    lw  $s3, 12($sp)
    lw  $s2, 8($sp)
    lw  $s1, 4($sp)
    lw  $s0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,24
    jr  $ra
```

I got this mostly from an [online resource](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ecs354-2/onyourown/arrays.html) on creating an array of integers, tweaking the values to work with strings of a constant length.

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: *"I got this ... on creating an array of integers"* - the alignment requirements of an integer and pointer are sometimes different.

Comment: I realize that. I thought I made the right adjustments but clearly not. And I've been staring at it just a bit too long to figure it out with a sound mind.

Comment: As a quick test, you might try adding an `align 4` to the *.S file. See, for example, the [Assembly HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Assembly-HOWTO/).

Comment: Nope. Still seem to get the same issue. The issue seems to be happening at the store word instruction, if that offers any necessary information (again this is happening after $t0 has been incremented to 1)

Comment: We need to see the relevant data declarations. If `$t0 += 1` is causing the `SIGBUS`, then you probably need to align the array members. Try allocating enough space to hold an aligned array, and then use `$t0 += 2` or `$t0 += 4`.

Comment: Add them to your question (and don't drop them in a comment). You can add them to the question by clicking *Edit*. Code in comments is usually unreadable.

Comment: Added. Anyway, I'm not sure I understand your suggestion for incrementing `$t0` by something other than 1. As it stands that's just a counter for the line number I'm on. It's not being directly used to add anything to the array, it's only being compared to my actual predetermined number of lines, `$s0`, which in the test I'm running is only 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `jal build_loop`, which is effectively recursion, not iteration.
Unfortunately, `jal build_loop` stores the return address to a register, (load-store-architecture, remember?) which happens to be `$ra` (GPR 31). This clashes badly with the rest of `build_loop`, which neglects to save `$ra` on the stack.
The result is, of course, that `$ra` is clobbered.

Comment: It had occurred to me when you said that that there was some stuff I had left out, including storing and loading `$ra` into and from the stack. It's been included now. My mistake.

Comment: The code you have posted still does not make sense: `$ra` is not saved **between `build_loop:` and `jal built_loop`**. You *do* realize MIPS has more branch/jump instructions than `jal`, right?

Comment: Well I did just try changing it to something as simple as `b`, but unfortunately the same error occurred at the same moment.